# nodejs .node-xmlhttprequest-sync-1 file created

Tags: node.js, express, google-cloud-functions

I am using google cloud function with nodejs12 runtime and I am getting the following error.

```
EROFS: read-only file system, open '.node-xmlhttprequest-sync-1'"
```

nodejs (express.js) is creating a file in same level as index.js which is not permitted (files should be created in /tmp/ in cloud functions)

- why is this file created
- if this is necessary, how to ensure its created in /tmp

Comment: These files are generated by `nodemon`.

Comment: Can you share your code?

Answer (score 2):

This file is created by the `node-XHMLHttpRequest` library when the `settings.async` flag is set to false: https://github.com/driverdan/node-XMLHttpRequest/blob/master/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js#L480

Are you or any functions you're importing using this library? If so, the quickest fix would be to use async requests.